# How to check NIC is valid?

Tags: vb.net

I want validate xxxxxxxxxV this nic number. I used this code for it. It doesn't work.

```
Public Function validateNIC(nicnumber) As Boolean
    Dim nic As New Regex("/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/")
    If nic.IsMatch(nicnumber) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What is a "NIC"?

Comment: @Dai : Seems to be something used in Sri Lanka: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identity_card_(Sri_Lanka)

Comment: Yes !! It's used in srilanka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex expressions in .NET should not be surrounded by slashes. Remove them and it should work.

```
Dim nic As New Regex("^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$")
```

Answer (score 2):

- .NET Regular Expressions don't use `/` as delimiters. You express them directly as strings.
- Your `If ... Return` syntax is verbose and can be simplified
- You can cache the `Regex` instance in a static (`Shared`) field for better performance, you can also specify `RegexOptions.Compiled` if your regex is evaluated often
- You should conform to .NET naming conventions and specify a type for the `nicnumber` parameter

```
Private Shared nicRegex As New Regex( "^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$", RegexOptions.Compiled )

Public Shared Function IsValidNicNumber(nicNumber As String) As Boolean

    Return nicRegex.IsMatch( nicNumber )

End Function
```